# A problem about injecting spring bean into jsf bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I met a problem when injecting spring bean into jsf bean,
which causes javax.faces.FacesException(Can't instantiate class),
             javax.faces.el.EvaluationException

Here is my xml files:

File WEB-INF/components.xml defines spring beans

```
<beans>
    <bean id="rambo.api.VideoService" 
    class="rambo.impl.VideoServiceImpl">

            <!-- some properties ... -->
    </bean>
</beans>
```

File WEB-INF/faces-config.xml define jsf beans

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Video Home Bean</description>
    <managed-bean-name>videoBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>rambo.tool.VideoBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>

    <managed-property>
            <description>videoService</description>
            <property-name>videoService</property-name>
            <value>#{Components["rambo.api.VideoService"]}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <!-- Other properties -->
</managed-bean>
```

File videoMain.jsp:

In resourceToolExists: the videoBean uses some methods of videoService

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{! videoBean.resourceToolExists" >
    <%@ include file="videoNoResource.jsp" %>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here gets:
  javax.faces.FacesException(Can't instantiate class rambo.impl.VideoServiceImpl),
  javax.faces.el.EvaluationException

Comment: what is `#{Components["rambo.api.VideoService"]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to config a spring elresolver in you faces-config.xml file. The spring elresolver will evaluate your el express and acquire the bean object defined in spring
Please check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html